# Python dataframe index adds NaN row

Tags: python, pandas

I have several CSVs and try to generate report from it.
The original CSVs has time column (hh:mm:ss) but it turns to string after read_csv.
Thus, I made time (seconds) list and make this list to index to dataframe as below:

```
from datetime import date, datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def genSec(frame, df):
    lenx = len(df.index)
    timex = []
    for i in range(0, lenx):
        timex.append((frame*float(i)))

    print(df.tail(4))
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=timex, data=df)
    # df.index = pd.to_timedelta(df.index, unit='seconds')

    return df

frame = 0.5

df0 = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=1, skiprows=([i for i in range(1, 2)]+[j for j in range(3, 8)]), comment='*', skip_blank_lines=True)
df0 = genSec(frame, df0)

print(df0.tail(4))
```

Results before 'index' in genSec:

```
2156  17:58.000000                 100.0          102.770998
2157  17:58.500000                 100.0          102.813514
2158  17:59.000000                 100.0          102.785460
2159  17:59.500000                 100.0          102.832991
```

Results after 'index' in genSec:

```
1078.0  08:59.000000                 100.0          109.275849
1078.5           NaN                   NaN                 NaN
1079.0  08:59.500000                 100.0          109.135326
1079.5           NaN                   NaN                 NaN
```

The problem comes from the line below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=timex, data=df)
```

It adds additional 'NaN' row to my original dataframe.
How to avoid this??

Additionally, Python version is 3.10.5

Comment: Try `df = pd.DataFrame(index=timex, data=df.set_axis(df.index * frame))`

Comment: What does your original CSV look like?

Comment: I solved this by searching others. `df.index = timex` works fine. But I still doesn't understahd that the method used above works in Python 3.8 but not in 3.10.